# SQL Query as transient RoR (ActiveRecord) model

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

Sadly I can't find much information on what I'm attempting to do. I'll try to break it down as briefly as possible.

I'm working with a legacy database, and believe me, it frustrates me too, but it is what it is so we've got to work within the parameters of that.

I've got a database with hundreds of thousands of rows, and a particularly ornery statistic/report that needs to be generated. Originally it was in one big query, but that makes it really frustrating to work with because it doesn't allow for very DRY architecting. I broke the query up into a few views and joined them together (ultimately in a final view) which worked fine for testing/development, but as I'm sure some of the more senior/experienced folks reading this may have guess already, it was quite slow. The most obvious way to speed it up was to apply the "where" clause to the inner views that were joined together. This sped the entire thing up by large orders of magnitude.

So, given that, I thought to myself

> Why can't I just make a model and define the big nasty union/select infested SQL that it should use and apply any where clauses on the model to each sub-select.

My thinking was that this would basically create a "virtual" model (I couldn't find anything by that name so I'm grasping here) that didn't really exist anywhere, but when "queried" it would return transient objects that have relationships (most likely to other more persistent models).

To illustrate, I'll post the big-nasty-sql. To give it perspective, it essentially is summarizing/counting statistics of affiliate sales etc.

```
SELECT
    `traffic`.`date` AS `date`,
    `traffic`.`site_id` AS `site_id`,
    `traffic`.`partner_id` AS `partner_id`,
    `traffic`.`visits` AS `visits`,
    `traffic`.`clicks` AS `clicks`,
    `traffic`.`signups` AS `signups`,
    `payout`.`signup_total` AS `signup_total`,
    `payout`.`upgrade_total` AS `upgrade_total`,
    `payout`.`recurring_total` AS `recurring_total`,
    `payout`.`referring_total` AS `referring_total`,
    `payout`.`negative_total` AS `negative_total`,
    `payout`.`fee_total` AS `fee_total`,
    `payout`.`carryover_total` AS `carryover_total`,
    `payout`.`adjustment_total` AS `adjustment_total`,
    `payout`.`payment_total` AS `payment_total`,
    `payout`.`payment_nums` AS `payment_nums`
    FROM (
        ((SELECT CAST(`traffic_date` AS DATE) AS `date`,
            `site_id`,
            `partner_id`,
            Sum(IF(tracking_type = 1, count, 0)) AS `visits`,
            Sum(IF(tracking_type = 6, count, 0)) AS clicks,
            Sum(0)                               AS signups
            FROM `tracking`.`tracking_partner_ad_event`
            WHERE `partner_id` = 1796279
            GROUP BY 1, 2, 3)
        UNION
        (SELECT CAST(`traffic_date` AS DATE) AS `date`,
            `site_id`,
            `partner_id`,
            Sum(count) AS visits,
            Sum(0)     AS clicks,
            Sum(0)     AS signups
            FROM `tracking`.`tracking_partner_traffic_visit`
            WHERE `partner_id` = 1796279
            GROUP BY 1, 2, 3)
        UNION
        (SELECT CAST(`processed_date` AS DATE) as `date`,
            `site_id`,
            `partner_id`,
            Sum(0) AS visits,
            Sum(0) AS clicks,
            Sum(1) AS signups
            FROM `user_account_entry`
            WHERE `trans_type` = 2 AND `status` <> 2 AND `partner_id` = 1796279
            GROUP BY 1, 2, 3)
        ) AS `traffic`
    JOIN
        (SELECT
            `period` AS `period_id`,
            `partner_id`,
            `processed_date`,
            `site_id`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=1, amount, 0)) AS `signup_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=2, amount, 0)) AS `upgrade_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=3, amount, 0)) AS `recurring_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=8, amount, 0)) AS `referring_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=4, amount, 0)) AS `negative_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=7, amount, 0)) AS `fee_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=9, amount, 0)) AS `carryover_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=5, amount, 0)) AS `adjustment_total`,
            SUM(IF(`payout_type`=6, amount, 0)) AS `payment_total`,
            GROUP_CONCAT(`payment_num` ORDER BY 1) AS `payment_nums`
        FROM `partner_account_entry` AS `e`
        WHERE `partner_id` = 1796279
        GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2
        ) AS `payout` ON (
        (
            (`traffic`.`date` = `payout`.`processed_date`) AND
            (`traffic`.`site_id` = `payout`.`site_id`) AND
            (`traffic`.`partner_id` = `payout`.`partner_id`)
        )
    )
) GROUP BY 1,2,3 ORDER BY 1
```

As you can see, by selecting on the `partner_id`, this query is significantly optimized.

TL;DR: I'd love to wrap the SQL above up in a model, even if any queries demand that a `partner_id` be supplied, to simulate a rails AR Object that could be passed around and further chained with.

Is this an unreasonable request? A herculean effort? How could this be done? I couldn't find existing examples, which worries me, but also bewilders me; isn't this a reasonable tactic and why doesn't a solution exist?